# printing out or returning strings between brackets

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function in similar manner as started, so that I will get what it's doing. I'm assuming this can be done with one line of code, with some fancy functions, but for the sake of practice and understanding I'm trying to come up with similar solution.

The task is the following: the function takes a text once it encounters enclosed square brackets [ word ] It should print out or return all words which are between square brackets. For example, if the text string would be "[a]n example[ string]", you are expected to print out "a string".

```
def string():
    text = "some random text [and I need this bit of txt] but I don't know how to continue [to get this bit as well]"
    for i in text:  
        for j in range(len(text)):
            if text[j] == '[':
                new = text.find(']')
                return(text[j+1:new])



print(string())
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: the issue is that I used return which obviously doesn't continue checking the following sequences, but if I use print it prints out multiple times "and I need this bit of text" , as many characters there are in the text that's how many times it prints.

Comment: Use [edit] to add explanations into the question; do not leave them in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def extract(text, skip_chars=("\n", )):
    output = ""
    flag = False
    for c in text:
        if c == "]":
            flag = False
        if flag and not c in skip_chars:
            output += c
        if c == "[":
            flag = True
    return output

print(extract("""[a]n example[ 
stri
ng]"""))
# -> "a string"
```

Comment: thank you, it seems so simply yet couldn't come up with this solution

Comment: sure. btw, I'll try using boolean as you did in my code. Meanwhile if you don't mind to take a look at my code I've posted here?

Comment: I would recommend you after you set `flag` write all chars to a temporary buffer and add them to `output` when you unset `flag`.

Comment: Also elif instead of if would make more sense?!

Comment: @EkoNezbit To be honest I don't think it would make that much difference...

Comment: true.. btw, with this approach how can I get rid of '\n' -s e.g. if text would be a long string text ="""The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog.[and desert you] Blowzy red vixens fight for a quick jump. Joaquin Phoenix was gazed 
by MTV for luck. A wizard’s job is to vex chumps quickly in fog. Watch "Jeopardy!", 
Alex Trebek's fun TV quiz game."""

Comment: Edited to fix :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse(source):
    i = source.index("[") # throw an exception
    result = ""

    while i < len(source):
        if s[i] == "[":
            i += 1
            while i < len(source):
                temp = ""
                if source[i] == "]":
                    result += temp
                    break;
                temp += source[i]
                i += 1
        i += 1

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def string():
    result = []
    text = "some random text [and I need this bit of txt] but I don't know how to continue [to get this bit as well]"
    for i in text:
        if i == '[':
            new = text.find(']')
            result.append(text[text.index(i) + 1:new])
    return " ".join(result)


print(string())
```

Comment: It prints out two times and I need this bit of text  without ' to get this bit as well
But this kind of approach suits me better, because I really wanted to solve it this way

Comment: You want to remove the space in between?